# python output from subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to write a simple software to scan some bluetooth devices (beacon with advertising) and I have a problem with the instruction `subprocess.Popen`

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['timeout','10s','hcitool','lescan'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE) 

    p1.wait()
    output, error = p1.communicate()
    print("stdout: {}".format(output))
    print("stderr: {}".format(error))
```

the output and error variables are empty!

If I remove the `stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE` from the `Popen` I can see the right  result in the console, if I change the command with `['ls','-l']` it works fine and I see the result in the variables .
I've tryed with `subprocess.run (with the timeout)` and it is the same.
If I don't use the timeout obviously the command never ends.
I can't use `pybluez` and my python version is the 3.7
Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't know what `hcitool` is, but this sounds like it could be a buffering issue. What happens if you pass `bufsize=1` (line-buffered) or `bufsize=0` (unbuffered) to `Popen`?

Comment: (If you use `bufsize=1`, you'll also have to pass `text=True`.)

Comment: Just tryed to add bufsize=1 or 0 but nothing change

Comment: I've tryed with text=true and it doesn't work, when I execute hcitool command from the console I see: 'root@acquatest2:~# hcitool lescan
LE Scan ...
53:64:D1:83:06:9D (unknown)
F8:77:B8:5F:C2:D5 (unknown)
D8:E0:E1:B3:22:D9 (unknown)
49:97:8E:37:CE:A5 (unknown)
49:97:8E:37:CE:A5 (unknown)
'

Answer (score 0):

Solved using ['timeout','-s','INT','10s','hcitool','lescan'] as command instead of ['timeout','10s','hcitool','lescan'].
Maybe in the second case the process was not killed well and I didn't receive the output.
Thank you the same.